# How to access table, related to pivot table in whereHas?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two models `One` and `Two`, related via pivot table 'one_two', which has own model `OneTwo` with hasOne Three.
Now I want to get all One instances filtered by value in Three.
This is what I tried and didn't success:

```
$ones = One::with('twos')->whereHas('twos', function ($q) {
    $q->where('threes.value', 'yes');
})->get();
```

How to do such thing?

Table `ones` : `id`,`field1`

Table `twos` : `id`,`field2`

Table `one_two` : `id`,`one_id`, `two_id`, `pivot_field`,

Table `threes` : `id`, `one_two_id`, `value`

One <=> Two: many to many

Three => OneTwo: one to one

Comment: Please can you show your table structure or the relationships for all 3 models?

Comment: updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this sort of thing, I don't think you can directly use relationships on a `Pivot` model due to the way laravel structures its many to many queries.

One way to get around this would be to define a `hasMany` relationship between `One` and `OneTwo` so that you can apply the constraints easily but it won't mean you have to give up your existing relationships (you're purely using this relationship to scope your query) i.e.

**One Model**

```
public function oneTwo()
{
    return $this-hasMany(OneTwo::class);
}
```

This way you can then structure you query like:

```
$ones = One::with('twos')->whereHas('oneTwos.three', function ($q) {
    $q->where('value', 'yes');
})->get();
```

In the above example I'm assuming you relationship is called `three` as it is a `hasOne` relationship. If it is `threes` you just need to change the `whereHas` relationship to `'oneTwos.threes'`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
 $ones = One::with('twos')->whereHas('one_two.threes', function ($q) {
    $q->where('value', 'yes');
 })->get();
```

Model ONE relationship with TWO :

```
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
 */
public function one_two()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Two','one_id','id');
}
```

Model OneTwo relationship with THREE :

```
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function three() {

    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Three','one_two_id');
}
```

Comment: I tried that, it says `Two does not have relation threes()`

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: `Two` is not related to `Three`, `OneTwo` is.

Comment: This is the method I used. Not sure is there any alternative available for this. Also if you see it as query, it will look like this

"select * from `one` where exists (select * from `two_three` where `one`.`id` = `two_three`.`one_id` and exists (select * from `three` where `two_three`.`three_id` = `three`.`id` and `id` = ?) and `two_three`.`deleted_at` is null) and `status` = ? and `posts`.`deleted_at` is null limit 10 "

I don't see any performance issue also. You can search for alternatives, if you find any please share

Comment: One <=> Two relationship is many to many and Three belongs to OneTwo